# Get facebook likes count of multiple pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am about to create a facebook page for a photo contest.

Say there will be 1000+ photos with unique URL ofc, and there is a function allows user to sort photos by "likes" count.

I know it is possible to run a query to get like count of each photo page, but how can I get the counts for each photo quickly?

Prefer hints of JS, PHP, or an general solution.

Here is an example site. https://www.facebook.com/svensktsmor/app_194886487348819

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to my colleague Robin, one solution will be:

FQL query is cleener: SELECT url, normalized_url,like_count FROM link_stat WHERE url IN 
('google.com','aftonbladet.se')

You will get the following data:

{
  "data": [
    {
      "url": "google.com", 
      "normalized_url": "http://www.google.com/", 
      "like_count": 1343662
    }, 
    {
      "url": "aftonbladet.se", 
      "normalized_url": "http://www.aftonbladet.se/", 
      "like_count": 10082
    }
  ]
}

Comment: link_stat is a database table but online, so you can treat it just as a database table. Shame on me!